# send information through a url from desktop based application

Tags: c#

i have to pass some information to a weburl and get a response in return from it.

This has to be done on a button click of a desktop based application made in c#.

Comment: Why is this not a real question? It's a little brief but it's certainly a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

// used on each read operation
byte[]        buf = new byte[8192];

// prepare the web page we will be asking for
HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.feefifofum.com/login.aspx?userid=XXX&pass=YYYY");

// execute the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// we will read data via the response stream
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

string tempString = null;
int    count      = 0;
do
{
    // fill the buffer with data
    count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    // make sure we read some data
    if (count != 0)
    {
        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

        // continue building the string
        sb.Append(tempString);
    }
}
while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

// print out page source
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

WebClient.[DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(VS.80).aspx), [UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(VS.80).aspx), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebClient.DownloadString and pass your values as QueryString. Something like below

```
string s;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.QueryString.Add ("Param1", "param1value");  
  wc.QueryString.Add ("Param2", "param2value");           
  s = wc.DownloadString (webaddress);
}
```

For method details visit  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Sending information to a URL and getting information back also sounds a bit like a job for a webservice. Have you considered using a webservice? (assuming you have control/access to the URL)